# Exception attempting to get original in message in apache camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, camel-spring-dsl

I'm trying to get the original message in my camel exception handler. I'm trying to call `exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()` but getting the following exception

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AllowUseOriginalMessage is disabled. Cannot access the original message.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultUnitOfWork.getOriginalInMessage(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:307)
```

How can I enable the `AllowUseOriginalMessage` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This can be enabled via `CamelContext.setAllowUseOriginalMessage(Boolean)`

eg:

```java
@Bean
public CamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext, List<RoutesBuilder> routeBuilders) throws Exception {
    SpringCamelContext context = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
    context.setAllowUseOriginalMessage(true);
    for (RoutesBuilder routeBuilder : routeBuilders) {
        context.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
    }   
    ...
    return context;
}

@Bean
public RoutesBuilder camelRoutes(...) {
   return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() { ... }
   }
}
```

See [RuntimeConfiguration.setAllowUseOriginalMessage(java.lang.Boolean)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/RuntimeConfiguration.html#setAllowUseOriginalMessage(java.lang.Boolean))